# Create a read-only file using filesaver.js

Tags: javascript, filesaver.js

Is it posible to create a read-only txt file using filesaver?

```
var blob = new Blob(["Hello, world!"], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
saveAs(blob, "hello world.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it posible to create a read-only txt file using filesaver?

No. Do not believe it is possible to create a `read-only` `Blob` using `javascript` alone. File permission needs to be set at user filesystem.

Comment: Thank you, is there any advice I can try?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? [`JSzip`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Stuk/jszip/master/dist/jszip.js) appears to set permissions of created `.zip` file

Comment: I need to generate txt file for bank-result using javascript, but the file must be read-only. I'm running out of options.

Comment: Note, setting permission of file to `read-only` would not prevent copy/paste of contents of file

Comment: Just not to change the contents of the file, that file will be read on another process

Comment: _"that file will be read on another process"_ Can you include `javascript` of "another process" at Question? Are you trying to access user filesystem after user saves file at user filesystem?

Comment: @MuhammadReizvan Have you tried using `LocalFileSystem` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/LocalFileSystem ?